# jsf passthrough elements button error primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I need this without PrimeFaces tags, but it doesn't work.

The html:

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <button jsf:id="myButton" onclick="alert('buttonClick');">Button</button>

</f:view>
```

Primefaces error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined 
>   (anonymous function) bI.event.dispatch cc.handle

Answer (score 0):

I believe a primefaces button should be:

```
<p:button outcome="outcome" value="myBUtton" icon="ui-icon-star">
    <f:param name="buttonId" value="1" />
</p:button>
```

If you are trying to pass a value (parameter) through a button

Comment: Oh, sorry! Just out of curiosity, why? :)

Comment: I intend to remove Primefaces in the future, however is a very large project, it would happen gradually